# Azure app uploads from VSCode without linking static sources

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I have an incredibly basic node.js server test app running on port 3000 in VSCode. The server appears to work via node on localhost or deployed to Azure, and hosts an index.html file. I have clients happy to talk to it.

```
    /* Server.js */
    
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.json());
    
    app.get("/", function(request, response){
        response.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });
    
    app.post("/", function(request, result){
        console.log(request.body["itema"] + " " + request.body["itemb"]);
        result.send("Pong!!");
    });
    
    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log("Server started on port 3000");
    });
```

```
    <!-- Index.html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
        
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Test!</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
    /*style.css*/

    h1 {
      color: tomato;
    }
```

[Azure Configuration Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCbMq.png)

---

The index.html links to a css file which doesn't appear to be linked when deployed. I've tried deploying the app to azurewebsites.net through VSCode, however I'm seeing the same results. Only index.html is present in the sources view. I get an error claiming it can't render the source it didn't find.

```
"Refused to apply style from https://<appname>.azurewebsites.net/style.css because its MIME 
type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is 
enabled."
```

If I view the advanced page (.scm.azurewebsites.net), again I can see only index.html.

[Index only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lknrp.png)

But .scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/ shows me the css file has been uploaded correctly.

[Index and linked sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfSCj.png)

I'm convinced it'll be a simple solution to someone and that the PATH variables will need to be set...somehow... but I've hit a brick wall and my Google-Fu has finally been exhausted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to server.js resolved the issue.

```
app.use(express.static("./"));
```

This is further explained here and is required in express to serve static files.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html